# Wage Calculation problems when adding in overtime hours

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am spending too much time on this which in theory is simple. My wage calculator only displays a value when hours exceed 40 hrs.  If I put less than 40 the output is £0.00? Some guidance would be appreciated:

```
hoursWorked = double.Parse(txtHoursWorked.Text); // change string to int

switch (rblJobRole.SelectedIndex)// set employees basic hourly rate
{
    case 0: //engineer
        basicHourRate = 10;
        break;
    case 1: //Senior Engineer
        basicHourRate = 12;
        break;
    case 2: //Technical Engineer
        basicHourRate = 25;
        break;
    case 3: //Supervisor
        basicHourRate = 30;
        break;
}

if (ckBEng.Checked) // if they have a certificate
{
    certAmount = (basicHourRate * 10) / 100; // calculate 10% of hourly rate
    basicHourRate = basicHourRate + certAmount; // add to hourly rate
    basicWage = basicHourRate * hoursWorked; // basic wage set to include bonus.
}

if (hoursWorked > 40) // if employee worked more than 40hrs
{
    overHrs = hoursWorked - regHrs; // calcualte over hours
    basicWage = regHrs * basicHourRate; // calculate basic wage @ 40hrs only
    overTimeRate = overHrs * (basicHourRate * 1.5); // calculate 50% bonus on 40+ hrs
    basicWage = basicWage + overTimeRate; // calculate total wage
}

lblTotalWage.Text = basicWage.ToString("c"); // int to string to display Total Wage on a label
lblDescWage.Text = "You have earned:  ";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they don't have a certificate (`ckBEng.Checked` is `false`), and they don't work > 40 hours (`hoursWorked <= 40`), they don't take money :-)

```
if (ckBEng.Checked)
{
}
```

you need an `else` here.

Or you move

```
basicWage = basicHourRate * hoursWorked;
```

outside the `if`

Comment: hehe doh! I just moved basicWage = basicHourRate * hoursWorked; oustide the if statement and it all works fine. Thank you very much :)